# Floating divs and right alignment

Tags: css, html, css-float, alignment

I really apologise if this question has already been answered somewhere else on the website.
I am fairly new to html & css and I am constantly getting stuck in the same place, floating divs.

I am trying to float three divs next to each other. However, as you might notice in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/_karima/aWaT2/), the right div is not right aligned with the other elements above and below it.

Is the problem with the width, padding, margins...?

http://jsfiddle.net/_karima/aWaT2/

CSS

```
#article {
    overflow:auto;
    }

    #left-column {
    background: yellow;
    width:19%;   
    height: 100px;
    }

    #main {
    background: yellow;
    width:39%;
    height: 300px;
    }


    #right-column {
    background: blue;
    width: 29%;
    height: 150px;

    }
    #left-column, #main, #right-column {    
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 7px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="article">
<div id="left-column"> left-column</div>
<div id= "main">main</div>
<div id="right-column"> right column</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your padding + margins + width must all add up to less than or equal to 100%, unless you add box-sizing:border-box (only works with newer browsers)

Comment: if you want something to float right and line up it needs to be above the other divs in your html - just 'cause

Comment: Im confused. So like this? [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aWaT2/1/) Or like [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aWaT2/2/)

Comment: Or like [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/aWaT2/4/). God im bored lol.

Comment: When writing code, please be sure to check your spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Try using box-sizing property

The box-sizing property allows you to define certain elements to fit an area in a certain way

Learn about it [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppollono/8Qy8n/1/)

```
#left-column, #main, #right-column {
    float: left;
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 7px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */    
}
```

Comment: Yes for sure! the problem here is the padding he is using px and thats pushing the width

Comment: width + padding + border = actual visible/rendered width of box ||||||||
height + padding + border = actual visible/rendered height of box